# Prove or disprove the following statement (matrix equation)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in \Bbb{C}^{n \times n}, B$ invertible and

$$
5A^2+3A-5B^T(B^{-1})^T=0
$$

**Then $A$ is invertible.**

What I did: $(B^{-1})^T=(B^T)^{-1}$ so:

$5A^2+3A-5B^T(B^{-1})^T=0 \iff 5A^2+3A-5I=0$

I know I didn't do much, but I don't know how to follow this, I tried using the quadratic equation but it got me nowhere.

Tips, not a complete solution, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you supposed to show? Right now, this question is incomplete.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Oh god, sorry, I'm tired. I just editted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $5A^2+3A-5I = 0$, we have $A^2+\tfrac{3}{5}A-I = 0$, i.e. $A^2+\tfrac{3}{5}A = I$.

Hence, $A(A+\tfrac{3}{5}I) = I = (A+\tfrac{3}{5}I)A$. What does this tell you about the matrix $A+\tfrac{3}{5}I$?

EDIT: Typo fixed. Thanks YoTengoUnLCD for catching that.

Comment: Oh I get it, it was really simple $-A- \frac 3 5 I = A^{-1}$, right? Thanks!

Comment: There's a typo in your answer, it should be $5A^2+3A-5I=0$!